# get error like this "The OpenTok API request failed: Stream not found" at the time of applying getStream function

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

We have generated stream id but when we pass stream id to getstream function then we are getting domain exception error.

I have attached following code...

public function index1(){

```
    $opentok = new OpenTok($this->config->item('opentok_key'), $this->config->item('opentok_secret'));

    $sessionId = "1_MX40NOTI2NH5-MTYzMjQ4MDI5MDY1Nn5tNTg0aHpSRjdoTTdDb1pHUDNKYUZuSGR-fg";
    $streamId = "cf91b5ac-f995-4f77-9c5a-23cf14325720";
    // print_r($streamId); exit();
    $stream = $opentok->getStream($sessionId, $streamId);
    // print_r($stream); exit();
    // // Stream properties
    // $stream->id; // string with the stream ID
    // $stream->videoType; // string with the video type
    // $stream->name; // string with the name
    // $stream->layoutClassList; // array with the layout class list

    $this->load->view('index1');
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.